# Popup resizing after button press

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

So I have a popup where there is a button. When you press that button, some random text comes up between 0 and 32 words. When that text comes up, almost every time popup resizes depending on number of words. I would just want that my button is always staying on the same place, so that you don't have to catch it every time you want to click it. Is there a way to lock that button in place?

Html for button:

```html
 <button onclick="function()" class="btn button-gradient">click</button>
```

css for button:

```css
.btn {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #9A0000;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: sounds like you need to set sizes. No clue what your code is so it is impossible to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the button above the text instead of below it. Funny thing is I've been in this position before. sometimes there are advanced coding ways to do it, sometimes it's a simple logic problem. try that out and let us know how it works.

Comment: It did solve it, thank you so much! But do you or anyone else have solution for this when button is placed beneath the text? I mean, is it even possible?

Comment: i would just set a height on the textbox that i felt would cover whatever text was going in it. For example, you might set the height to 300px (because sometimes it was 200px, sometimes 50px, etc.) you could also set the box to scroll https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp in case it was bigger than 300px. this way it would stay the same size but you could scroll it. let me know how that works!

Comment: Thanks! I did set the height and width and now works flawlessly!